# ZLS vs 1 char space

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Something that has totally shocked me, and made me feel like an absolute fool.

```
select count(*) as [row count], myField as FieldValue, len(myField) as ValueLength
from myTable
where myField=N''
group by myField,len(myField)
```

Returns a record with a healthy Count, and  [ValueLength] of 0.

Now if I change the WHERE clause to : `where myField=N' '`
(i.e. change from a ZLS to a {space})

The query now returns exactly the same result ?

How can this be?
Surely SQL Server knows the difference between a ZSL and a space ?
May it's me that does not understand !?

Please can someone enlighten me as to what's going on under the hood here ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because of padding in order to compare strings of same length:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: An additional note; the behavior is (afaik) limited to SQL Server and is not a standard SQL behavior.